# Currently trying to print out Reversal class while using command line arguments

Tags: java

I've been trying multiple different ways but can't seem to figure out how to get the string reversal to work in command line.

```
public class Reversal {
static void reverseChar(String input) {
    char output[] = new char[input.length()];
    int i = input.length();
    while (i > 0) {
        output[++i] = input.charAt(i);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

}

Comment: `output = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString().toCharArray()` This also works correctly for strings containing surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Reversal {
    static void reverseChar(String input) {
        char output[] = new char[input.length()];
        int i = input.length();
        int count=0;
        while (i > 0) {
            output[count++] = input.charAt(--i);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverseChar("Tharindu");
    }
}
```